# Can we use webservice on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, web-services, notifications, watchkit

I am working on iwatch notification application want to send status change data to webservice on reading notification on iwatch,is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am making NSURL calls and sending UDP packets in this video: http://youtu.be/BhaDy6TmGYg

Comment: hi Gary, can you share any demo project

Comment: I can't I'm afraid. I have only done this in my commercial project I am unable to provide source for.

Answer (score 0):

As with a normal iOS notification, your application doesn’t get informed when the user sees your notification, only when they select an action you’ve defined on it. For information on that, see [Using Notification Actions in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26) and—for the WatchKit-specific aspects—[Notification Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html).